# change language in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, javascript-framework

I would like to change the language of my grid that I constructed with jqGrid. 
For column names I use server side localization like this:

```
mtype: 'POST',
colNames:['', '$l10n.col1', '$l10n.col2', '$l10n.col3','$l10n.col4', '$l10n.col5','$l10n.col6','$l10n.col7 $l10n.col8','$l10n.col9','$l10n.col10']
```

This code is parsed by the `Velocity` template engine which knows how to handle my `$l10n` localization tool. But there are jqGrid specific texts (like to Loading... label or the Page label etc.) I have seen these labels are in the `grid.locale-xx.js` files.

I want to use the labels from `grid.locale-en.js` instead of the labels from `grid.locale-de.js` when I change my application's language. Where can I tell jqGrid which localization file to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) has an example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization.htm) which should be exactly what you need.

Comment: & @Atticus: I want only add that my suggestion (feature request) is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/#p22314). One more powfull link is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm). It't pity that Tony (the developer of jqGrid) not follows the suggestion, but my changes are made so that **only the changes in *"i18n/grid.locale-XX.js"* should be done, so you can use my suggestion without modifying of the main jqGrid code.